# How to prevent multiple login on same browser in rails? [Rails 5.0]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi i am working on a rails project, i am using ActiveAdmin for admin section, currently both user and admin can get login at same time, but i want to allow only one type of login at a time on the same browser.
i.e. If a user is login then admin can not get login on the same browser until that user gets logout.

Note: i am using device for user authentication, and ActiveAdmin for backend.

Comment: `User` and `Admin` are separate models and both use email for login?

Comment: @PavelTkackenko yes

Answer (score 0):

As ActiveAdmin using the Devise gem, you can use these Helpers

```
user_signed_in?     # Checks whether there is a user signed in or not
admin_signed_in?    # Checks whether there is an admin signed in or not
```